# How to pass Python doctest with plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, doctest

Is there a way or trick to pass doctest, when output is matplotlib object? Doctest framework I also use for examples of code (not only for testing output)

So my problem looks like this:

```
    plt.plot(grid, pdf); plt.title('Random Normal 1D using Kernel1D.kde function'); plt.grid(); plt.show()
Expected nothing
Got:
    [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000208BDA8E2B0>]
    Text(0.5, 1.0, 'Random Normal 1D using Kernel1D.kde function')
```

What I would like to happen, is to pass doctest when I plot anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [doctest.ELLIPSIS](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS) to make a string match to anything.

Your code will still show problems in the `plt.show()` if you want to avoid seeing the plots and go directly to the report of the evaluation. For that you can use [doctest.SKIP](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/doctest.html#doctest.SKIP). Check the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test():
    """
    Code example:

    >>> 1 + 1
    2
    >>> plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
    [...
    >>> plt.show() #doctest: +SKIP
    >>> plt.close()
    """
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

This returns the following report:

```
Trying:
    1 + 1
Expecting:
    2
ok
Trying:
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
Expecting:
    [...
ok
Trying:
    plt.close()
Expecting nothing
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   3 tests in __main__.test
3 tests in 2 items.
3 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```